# Use Custom Field to Display Post Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

In my custom template I have created a menu which is a row of 10 horizontal tabs. Each tab shows a date which is defined using an ACF datepicker field in the post.

I have also created a custom post type called 'Events' where I have added an ACF Date-picker custom field with the key 'grid_date'.

I want to display the Event post under the tab, when both dates match. For example in Tab 1 I add the date 01/09/2023. Any Events posts that also have this date defined in the Event posts ACF datepicker should display under my Tab 1.

I have tried and my tabs display as shown in picture below, but there is no output of Events posts. There are no console errors.

[image: tabs image]

Referring to image attached. As a test, I have added the value ‘01/09/2023’ to the ACF Date-picker field in one Events post. Therefore, every instance of tabs with the date ‘01/09/2023’ should display this post, however there is no output.

```php
<div class="date-columns">
    <?php
    // Array of ACf field names for each heading's Date Picker value
    $acf_field_names = array(
        'date_field_1', 'date_field_2', 'date_field_3', 'date_field_4', 'date_field_5',
        'date_field_6', 'date_field_7', 'date_field_8', 'date_field_9', 'date_field_10'
    );

    // Loop throug headings and display events posts under respective heading
    foreach ($acf_field_names as $acf_field_name) {
        $heading_date = get_field($acf_field_name); // Get the ACF Date Picker value

        // Initialize array for events posts matching the heading's date
        $events_for_heading = array();

        // Query events posts with matching ACF Date Picker value
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'events', // Update to the post type slug "events"
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'grid_date', // ACF Date Picker field in events posts
                    'value' => $heading_date,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        );

        $events_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($events_query->have_posts()) {
            while ($events_query->have_posts()) {
                $events_query->the_post();
                $events_for_heading[] = get_the_ID(); // Store events post ID
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

        // Display Heading and its events posts
        echo '<div class="heading">';
        echo '<h3>' . $heading_date . '</h3>';

        foreach ($events_for_heading as $event_id) {
            $event_content = get_post_field('post_content', $event_id);
            $event_link = get_permalink($event_id);
            $event_detail = get_field('detail', $event_id);

            echo '<div class="post">';
            echo '<h4><a href="' . $event_link . '">' . get_the_title($event_id) . '</a></h4>';
            echo '<p>' . $event_content . '</p>';
            echo '<p class="detail"><strong>Detail:</strong> ' . $event_detail . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Style

```css
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .date-columns {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .heading {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    
    .post {
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    .post h4 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
    }
    
    .detail {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: you need to tell it you want to use post meta to order the posts, but that should have nothing to do with the console errors you mentioned, you would need to share them too. Note that you want to store the dates in a MySQL compatible format, you can always change the format on display if you want users to see a different date format, but if your data does not follow a compatible format then date sorting will be impossible. E.g. `2020/12/30` is a compatible date format ( and an ISO standard date format ), `Wednesday the 10th of December` is not

Comment: @TomJNowell I have the edited the grammar of my question slightly. There are no console errors showing. Both ACF datepicker fields follow the same value format which is m/d/Y.